# Unable to connect to server - pgAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection, pgadmin

[image]

The error information:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost:3000" (183.221.250.11) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My config is below:

[image]

**Additional**

I have run `$ rails s`.

---

**Attempt -1**

I changed the Host to `localhost`, and the Port to `3000`:

[image]

But get this error:

[image]

> Unable to connect to server:
>   received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H

Comment: What configuration did you put in while connecting?

Comment: The error window title says "Unauthorized". Did you provide your DB correct username and password to pgAdmin connection?

Comment: @VAD, I update my post with my `User name` and `Password`, you take a look, and where to see the `User name` and `Password` if is correct?

Comment: Hold on. You've got hostname as `localhost:3000`. But hostname must be `localhost`. `3000` is port

Comment: I changed Host to `localhost` and Port to `3000`, but shows to `Unable to connect to server:

received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H`